# How to Override vcl_hash Method in Varnish 4

Tags: varnish

I have the following code snip-it for Varnish 2 to only include a subset of fields in it's hashing logic.

```
sub vcl_hash {
  set req.http.temp = regsub(req.url, "^.*[?&](q=[^&]*).*$", "\1");
  set req.http.temp2 = regsub(req.url, "^.*[?&](limit=[^&]*).*$", "\1");
  set req.http.temp3 = regsub(req.url, "^.*[?&](classes=[^&]*).*$", "\1");
  set req.http.temp3 = regsub(req.url, "^.*[?&](offset=[^&]*).*$", "\1");
  set req.hash += req.http.temp;
  set req.hash += req.http.temp2;
  set req.hash += req.http.temp3;
  set req.hash += req.http.temp4;
  return(hash); 
}
```

How can I convert this code to work with Varnish 4?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in function `hash_data`

First, call the `hash_data` function with your url but without the query string.
Then call again the `hash_data` function for every fields you want to add to the hash logic.

You should end up with something like that :

```
sub vlc_hash {
  hash_data(__YOUR_REQUEST_WITHOUT_QUERY_STRING__);
  hash_data(regsub(req.url, "^.*[?&](q=[^&]*).*$", "\1"));
  hash_data(regsub(req.url, "^.*[?&](limit=[^&]*).*$", "\1"));
  hash_data(regsub(req.url, "^.*[?&](classes=[^&]*).*$", "\1"));
  hash_data(regsub(req.url, "^.*[?&](offset=[^&]*).*$", "\1"));
  return (lookup);
}
```

Note that your `vlc_hash` function must return `lookup` to abort the execution of the default VCL.

You can read the documentation of the Varnish 4 hashing logic at the following address https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/vcl-hashing.html

Comment: I remember trying something almost identical to this.  The only thing that I omitted was the hash_data(__YOU_REQUEST_WITHOUT_QUERY_STRING__) part.  However, I could never get the hash to ignore the rest the the URL.  Maybe there's some sort of bug in the version I'm using?

Comment: What is the major and minor number of the version you are using?